# MySQL 5.7 Community Server End of Life/Support

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is there any official document that outlines the date till which MySQL Community Server 5.7 will receive security updates/patches? I see that page 20 of [this document](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf) from Oracle outlines Premier and Extended Support end date for MySQL 5.7, but I am not sure if it is talking about Community Server Edition or MySQL Enterprise Edition. Is there a relation between extended support end date listed in the document and the date till which MySQL 5.7 will receive security patches?

Also, are security fixes released to Community Server first and then hardened and released to Enterprise edition of same MySQL version? Or are they released to Enterprise edition first and then to Community Server edition?

Short version of my question: Till what date will MySQL 5.7 Community Server get security patches? :)

Thanks

Comment: Note that it's actually page 27 as printed, page 28 in the PDF, that discusses MySQL, not page 20. The document may have changed after OP linked it.

Comment: I to have had difficulty finding an official source of MySQL community edition version end-of-life dates. However, AWS has the same 5.7 end-of-life date as endoflife.date/mysql does on the following web page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Concepts.VersionMgmt.html which brings a lot of trust as I doubt AWS would publish incorrect information.

Answer (score 13):

As per MySQL documentation [here](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql) the below you can find the life cycle for each version of application MySQL

**Current releases**

```
Release        Release date              End of life

MySQL 8.0      April 19, 2018       
MySQL 5.7      October 21, 2015          October 21, 2023   
MySQL 5.6      February 5, 2013          February 5, 2021
```

**All releases**

```
Release        Release Date            End of life  

MySQL 8.0      April 19, 2018       
MySQL 5.7      October 21, 2015       October 21, 2023  
MySQL 5.6      February 5, 2013       February 5, 2021  
MySQL 5.5      December 3, 2010       December 3, 2018  
MySQL 5.1      November 14, 2008      December 31, 2013 
MySQL 5.0                             January 9, 2012
```

For further your ref [here](https://www.fromdual.com/support-for-mysql-from-oracle) and [here](https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html)

Comment: As an addendum to "Till what date will MySQL 5.7 Community Server get security patches?", MySQL has been known to release security patches for discontinued versions for large impact issues, but of course you cannot count on it.

Comment: @jynus, Thanks for more information about the security patches of MySQL 5.7 Community Server.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! @Md Haidar Ali Khan The links that you provided that do not go to MySQL website, can they be considered as an official communication? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am new to this. I couldn't find information about MySQL 5.7 in the only link out of the three that goes to MySQL.com

Comment: @code2002 I found this link from wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history : https://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf says MySQL Database 5.7's extended support will end at Oct 2023.

Comment: I too would like to know where "endoflife.software" gets their info. It would be much better to hear from a MySQL or Oracle website.

Answer (score 0):

Based on past patch history the community server vs the commercial/enterprise edition both get the same patches at the same time and have the same EOL

Answer (score 0):

From https://endoflife.date/mysql:

| Release | Released | Premier Support | Extended Support | Latest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.7 | 7 years ago (09 Oct 2015) | Ended 2 years and 4 months ago (31 Oct 2020) | Ends in 8 months (31 Oct 2023) | 5.7.41 (07 Dec 2022) |

> ### Premier Support
>
> 5 years, starting at GA, of Premier Support that includes MySQL maintenance releases, updates, fixes (error correction), and security alerts.
>
> ### Extended Support
>
> 3 years of extra support including error correction, beyond the Premier Support period, for specific MySQL releases. Includes MySQL maintenance releases, updates, bug fixes (error correction), and security alerts.
>
> ### Sustaining Support
>
> Any time, beyond the Premier Support period. Support only. No new releases, no new fixes (no error correction for new issues), no new updates. Only pre-existing updates, fixes and alerts are available.
>
> ### Community Edition
>
> MySQL Community Edition is freely available under GPLv2 licensing. Historically, patches have been released at the same time as for the commercial offerings, but no official commitment is made that such a policy will remain.